# Implementing `__dir__` in Python: Does it need to return a list and does the list need to be sorted?

Tags: python, built-in

I have a class that implements the `__dir__` method. However, I am not entirely certain about some nitty gritty details of the `dir` API.

**A**: Is it really required that `__dir__` returns a list? My implementation is using a `set` to avoid listing attributes twice, do I need to convert it to a list before returning? From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) I would guess it has to be a list:

> If the object has a method named **dir**(), this method will be called
>   and must return the list of attributes.

However, would not returning a list break functionality at some point?

---

**B**: Does the result need to be sorted? The documentation is a bit ambiguous here:

> The resulting list is sorted alphabetically.

Does this mean, calling the built-in `dir` automatically sorts data returned by `__dir__` or does it mean `dir` expects sorted data from `__dir__`?

EDIT: Btw, my question encompasses Python 2 (2.6 and 2.7) and 3 (3.3, 3.4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Python 2.7.3, the answers are:

A: Yes, it must be a list:

```
>>> class F:
...     def __dir__(self):
...             return set(['1'])
... 
>>> dir(F())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __dir__() must return a list, not set
```

B: No, `dir` will sort it.

```
>>> class G:
...     def __dir__(self):
...             return ['c','b','a']
... 
>>> dir(G())
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 2):

Under Python 3, [you can return any sequence](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__dir__), including a set, and you need not sort it.

The corresponding documentation doesn't exist under Python 2, so I'm not sure what you're expected to do there.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, it must be a `list`. Otherwise you get a `TypeError` when you run the `dir()` function on a corresponding instance.

```
class Dirry(object):
    def __dir__(self):
        return set('andy pandy mandy sandy'.split())

d = Dirry()
dir(d)
```

Yields:

```
      5 d = Dirry()
----> 6 dir(d)

TypeError: __dir__() must return a list, not set
```

If returned as a list, it does not need to be sorted. The `dir()` function will sort for you:

```
class DirryList(object):
    def __dir__(self):
        return 'andy pandy mandy sandy'.split()

d = DirryList()
dir(d)
```

Yields:

```
['andy', 'mandy', 'pandy', 'sandy']
```

Even though it was not given by `__dir__` in sorted order.